# The name 'media' does not exist in the current context

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3

In an ASP.NET MVC 3 razor view, I have the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
    table { page-break-inside:auto; width: 100%; }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
```

However I got the error:

```
The name 'media' does not exist in the current context.
```

Thanks.

Comment: You get that error when?

Comment: Before debug, on the screen there is a red wave line under the word.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The `@` is a reserved character in Razor.  But you can escape it using `@@`:

```
@@media print
```

Answer (score 17):

In razor views the `@` symbol is the magic character which precedes code.

In your case, use 2 `@@` symbols; otherwise razor will think this is a code/expression block.

For example:

```
@@media print.
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Html.Raw` method:

```
@Html.Raw("@")media print
```

One example usage is when printing a Twitter handle, which has the `@` character in it.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx) is a good msdn link to know more about `razor` syntax and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) is one from Phil Hack.