# Resize a Object based on Web Browser's Size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem to make a web browser's size at least 768px. If the size is more than 768 px the field size should be applied to specified to 200 px in VS at cshtml

The CSS code is applied in the CShtml

When I execute the css code, I retrieve a message saying "The name 'media' does not exist in the current context".

This code below works perfectly at W3C's website but not in my context.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

I'm using VS, jquery, bootstrap.

```
/* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
@media (min-width: 768px) {


fieldset{
width: 200;
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612413/the-name-media-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context see this link

Comment: i think you not provided px in fieldset css it should be like 200px or in %

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `@media`, use `@@media` in VS. In VS `@` is a reserved character as far as I know.